# Play in feed facebook audio file

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, audio

I fallow this post: https://www.jwplayer.com/blog/publish-your-videos-to-facebook-with-a-jw-player/

To play my audio files on facebook, and I saw who youtube set the properties on metatag section for that action.

And I try to replicate that on my audio file, and work only with a static html, but when I make a dinamic file with express, nodejs and amazon doenst work

If you check the debug tool for facebook says that og:image is wrong or missing: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Ftest.mdzradio.com%2Faudios%2Fshare%2F577ea3e92a3ab98c18b037db

But if you see the source of the URL the metatag is there.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Title of the audio</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Diario" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="{{http}}/audios/share/{{audioId}}" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="{{name}}" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/radiomdz/images/FpR1JTd.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="200" />
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="200" />

    <meta property="og:description" content="{{description}}" />

    <meta property="og:type" content="video" />
    <meta property="og:video:url" content="https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/radiomdz/audios/player.swf?file={{audioUrlEncoded}}&autostart=true" />
    <meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/radiomdz/audios/player.swf?file={{audioUrlEncoded}}&autostart=true" />
    <meta property="og:video:type" content="text/html" />
    <meta property="og:video:width" content="400" />
    <meta property="og:video:height" content="40" />
    <meta property="og:video:url" content="https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/radiomdz/audios/player.swf?file={{audioUrlEncoded}}&autostart=true" />
    <meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/radiomdz/audios/player.swf?file={{audioUrlEncoded}}&autostart=true" />
    <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
    <meta property="og:video:width" content="400" />
    <meta property="og:video:height" content="40" />

    <meta property="og:video:tag" content="Radio" />
    <meta property="og:video:tag" content="Radio" />
    <meta property="og:video:tag" content="Radio" />

    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="595357037290855" />

    <script src="{{http}}/js/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
    <script>jwplayer.key="iWIqfC4bEJIOjuvBSzixtN4wOjqOgHz7FKSbrwVpCbc=";</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
    playerInstance.setup({
        file: "{{audioUrl}}",
        image: "{{audioImage}}",
        height: 40,
        width: 400,
        autostart: true
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can test with this URL: 
http://ec2-52-35-59-187.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/audios/share/577ea3e92a3ab98c18b037db

Comment: Both URLs are behind HTTP authentication. And since the debug tool’s “See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL” shows a minimal document containing “Access denied” only, I assume you did not implement any exceptions for the FB scraper …?

Comment: Thanks @CBroe the problem was the HTTP Authentication, I made a workaround for the facebook referer.